# Accelerator on a Turntable

Tags: mass, acceleration, relativity

If a circular particle accelerator were placed on a "frictionless" turntable and then turned on, would it spin opposite to the motion of the accelerating particles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of accelerator. The standard image you see have a circular track and particles going one way. As it accelerates them, by conservation of angular momentum it ought to rotate in the opposite direction on the turntable. It would be going slowly, since the mass of the accelerator is a lot higher than the beam, despite the speed.

However, accelerators like LHC use [counter-rotating beams](http://universe-review.ca/R15-20-accelerators03.htm) going in opposite directions (much easier to make them intersect and produce collisions). This means that the total angular momentum is zero: the LHC would not turn on the turntable.